# CDN Detector Extension / Script

Tags: proxy, reverse-proxy, cdn

Here is the scenario / task:

The user is browsing online and as soon as he/she runs into a website that uses CDN (for example CloudFlare or any other reverse proxy) the browser the user is using has to do the following:

Either

1. Warn the user that the site is on CDN / reverse proxy.

or

2. Block the site by saying it's on CDN / reverse proxy.

Are there any extensions / plug in / scripts to achieve this? Would appreciate any comments / suggestions / insights. Many thanks in advance!